# Making AWK code more efficient when evaluating sets of records

Tags: awk, refactoring, subroutine

I have a file with 5 fields of content. I am evaluating 4 lines at a time in the file. So, records 1-4 are evaluated as a set. Records 5-8 are another set. Within each set, I want to extract the time from field 5 when field 4 has the max value. If there are duplicate values in field 4, then evaluate the maximum value in field 2 and use the time in field 5 associated with the max value in field 2.

For example, in the first 4 records, there is a duplicate max value in field 4 (value of 53). If that is true, I need to look at field 2 and find the maximum value. Then print the time associated with the max value in field 2 with the time in field 5.

```html
The Data Set is:

 00        31444      8.7        24    00:04:32
 00        44574     12.4        25    00:01:41
 00        74984     20.8        53    00:02:22
 00        84465     23.5        53    00:12:33
 01        34748      9.7        38    01:59:28
 01        44471     12.4        37    01:55:29
 01        74280     20.6        58    01:10:24
 01        80673     22.4        53    01:55:49
```

The desired Output for records 1 through 4 is 00:12:33
The desired output for records 5 through 8 is 01:10:24

Here is my answer:

Evaluate Records 1 through 4

awk 'NR==1,NR==4 {if(max <= $4) {max = $4; time = $5} else if(max == $4) {max = $2; time = $5};next}END {print time}' test.txt test.txt

Output is: 00:12:33

Evaluate Records 5 through 8

awk 'NR==5,NR==8 {if(max <= $4) {max = $4; time = $5} else if(max == $4) {max = $2; time = $5};next}END {print time}' test.txt test.txt

Output is 01:10:24

Any suggestions on how to evaluate the record ranges more efficiently without having to write an awk statement for each set of records?

Thanks

Comment: Is your input always a multiple of 4 lines or could there be fewer than 4 lines in the final block (e.g. given 15 lines of input)?

Comment: Bythe way, I think instead of "more efficient" you mean "more concise" - you don't appear to be asking how to make your code run faster or use less memory, but instead how to write less code.

Comment: @RavinderSing13 raised a good question in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584744/making-awk-code-more-efficient-when-evaluating-sets-of-records/73585373?noredirect=1#comment129951632_73585373) - if $2 in your 3rd input line was `84465` then $4 and $2 would be identical for the 3rd and 4th lines so which $5 value should be output - the first from the input, the last from the input, the earliest time, the latest time, or based on the value of $3 (and then what if that is also identical) or does it not matter?

Comment: If $2 and $4 have duplicate values, the time value can be either the first time or second time value.  If all of the values in $2 are duplicate, the time value doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed to the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample input, the fact there's 4 lines for each key (first field) seems to be irrelevant and what you really want is to just produce output for each key so consider sorting the input by your desired comparison fields (field 4 then field 2) then printing the first desired output (field 5) value seen for each block per key (field 1):

```
$ sort -n -k1,1 -k4,4r -k2,2r file | awk '!seen[$1]++{print $5}'
00:12:33
01:10:24
```

Comment: This is very Good approach sir ++ve for sharing. One question: we don't need `-s` option here for `sort`? Sorry I am always confused with that option.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 good question. The OP doesn't say which $5 to print if $1, $2, and $4 are identical for 2 input rows - if they said "print  the first one from the input" THEN we'd need `-s` or some other way to keep the $5 values in input order after sorting on $1, $4, and $2. Without `-s` to preserve input order, given identical values for the key fields sort will do a final sort on the whole line to determine output order.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584744/making-awk-code-more-efficient-when-evaluating-sets-of-records/73585373?noredirect=1#comment129956413_73584744) about the OPs requirements for the case of identical keys, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: If $2 and $4 have duplicate values, the time value can be either the first time or second time value. If all values are duplicate in $2 and $4, the time doesn't matter. Thank you for the suggestions. They are all interesting to review.

Answer (score 3):

This awk code

```
NR % 4 == 1 {max4 = $4; max2 = $2}
$4 > max4 || $4 == max4 && $2 >= max2 {max4 = $4; max2 = $2; val5 = $5}
NR % 4 == 0 {printf "lines %d-%d: %s\n", (NR - 3), NR, val5}
```

outputs

```
lines 1-4: 00:12:33
lines 5-8: 01:10:24
```

---

Looking at the data, you might want to group sets by $1 instead of hardcoding **4** lines:

```bash
awk '
    function emit(nr) {printf "lines %d-%d: %s\n", nr - 3, nr, val5}

    $1 != setId {
        if (NR > 1) emit(NR - 1)
        setId = $1
        max4 = $4
        max2 = $2
    }
    $4 > max4 || $4 == max4 && $2 >= max2 {max4 = $4; max2 = $2; val5 = $5}
    END {emit(NR)}
' data
```

Answer (score 0):

an `awk`-based solution that utilizes a synthetic `ascii`-string-comparison key combining `$4` and `$5`, while avoiding any `%-modulo` operations :

```
 mawk '
 BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%020.f" (__=___=____=_____="")

  _+=_+=++_ } { ____= __!=(__=__==$((_____=(+$_ "")"(" $NF)^!_) \
                      ? __ : $!!_) || ____<_____ ? _____ : ____
 } _==++___ {

     printf(" group %-*s [%*.f, %-*.f] :: %s\n", --_*--_, "\"" (__) "\"", _+_,
            NR-++_, ++_, NR, substr(____, index(____, "(")+_^(_____=____=___=""))) }'


group "00"   [   1, 4   ] :: 00:12:33
group "01"   [   5, 8   ] :: 01:10:24
```

Comment: Great Googley Moogley! I have no idea how to read this, but thanks anyway! :)